# Compare data from two different models in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I created two models

```
from statistics import mode
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="myimage")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shape = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')

class final(models.Model):
    fshape = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    fcolor = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    fnmae = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    fdescr = models.TextField(max_length=50, default='')
```

I want to compare the shape from Image model with final model fshape
if shape and fshape are equal then display fshape

Comment: You can get both shapes using queryset, compare and return what you want

Comment: Do you want to check for specific instance or all ?